# Select periodic columns in R

Tags: r, select, subset

I have a matrix. For each row, I would like to select several elements on a periodic basis. For example, for the first row, I would like to pick up the 1st element, (1+a)th element, (1+2a)th element,..., till (1+ka)th element.

That is to say, for each row, I have a known frequency a, and a total number of elements to be drawn k. And I would like to do this selection process for all rows.

Sorry for the misinformation. What I want to say that, each row has a **different** frequency and a **different** total number of elements to be drawn.

For example, we have the following matrix.

```
m=t(matrix(1:100,50,2))

frequency=c(3,4)
numbers=c(6,5)
```

This means that, for the first row, I would like to draw 6 elements in total, for every 3 elements starting at the 1st element.
For the second row, I would like to draw 5 elements in total, for every 5 elements starting at the 1st element.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You could just use modular maths. `apply(my_matrix, 1, function(x) x[(seq_along(x) - 1) %% a == 0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with vectorized row/column indexing without any loop and is a one-liner as well if we change the assignment steps

```
a <- 2
j1 <- c(1, 1 + seq_len(ncol(m1)) * a)
j2 <- j1[j1 <= ncol(m1)]
m1[cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(m1)), each = length(j2)), j2)]
#[1]  1 21 41 61 81  2 22 42 62 82  3 23 43 63 83  4 24 44 64 84  5 25 45 65 85  6 26 46 66 86  7 27 47 67 87  8 28 48 68 88  9 29 49 69 89 10 30 50 70
#[50] 90
```

---

Using the OP's updated data

```
lapply(seq_along(numbers), function(i) m[i,seq(1, by = frequency[i], length.out = numbers[i])])
#[[1]]
#[1]  1  4  7 10 13 16

#[[2]]
#[1] 51 55 59 63 67
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(1:100, 10, 10)
```

Comment: Sorry about the misinformation. What I meant is that each row has a different frequency and total elements to be drawn.

Comment: @QuVergil Please update your post with a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: @QuVergil just saw your update.  I updated the post. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can split the data at each row and use it in `Map`. We can create a sequence from 1 by step of `frequency` with the length of `numbers` and subset those values.

```
Map(function(x, y, z) z[seq(1, by = x, length.out = y)],
                      frequency, numbers, asplit(m, 1))

#[[1]]
#[1]  1  4  7 10 13 16

#[[2]]
#[1] 51 55 59 63 67
```

**data**

```
m = t(matrix(1:100,50,2))
frequency = c(3,4)
numbers = c(6,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a one-liner with some modular math and indexing in an `apply` call:

```r
my_matrix <- matrix(1:100, byrow = TRUE, nrow = 10)
a <- 3
my_matrix
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#>  [2,]   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20
#>  [3,]   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29    30
#>  [4,]   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39    40
#>  [5,]   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49    50
#>  [6,]   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59    60
#>  [7,]   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69    70
#>  [8,]   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79    80
#>  [9,]   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89    90
#> [10,]   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99   100

t(apply(my_matrix, 1, function(x) x[(seq_along(x) - 1) %% a == 0]))
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#>  [1,]    1    4    7   10
#>  [2,]   11   14   17   20
#>  [3,]   21   24   27   30
#>  [4,]   31   34   37   40
#>  [5,]   41   44   47   50
#>  [6,]   51   54   57   60
#>  [7,]   61   64   67   70
#>  [8,]   71   74   77   80
#>  [9,]   81   84   87   90
#> [10,]   91   94   97  100
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Sorry about the misinformation. What I meant is that each row has a different frequency and total elements to be drawn.